# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Node JS using protractor

Tags: node.js, request, protractor

I'm using this method to request a tokenDn

```
this.retornaTokenDnQA  = function (Request, tokenAuth) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Request.get({
                    "headers": { "content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + tokenAuth }, 
                    "url": "https://urlqa-api.apps.pd01e.edc1.cf.company.com/transformation/api/jwt/generate",
                    "body": JSON.stringify({
                        "dn": "5094",
                        "claims": {
                            "country": "BRA",
                            "division": 1,
                            "user": "ULSCA301",
                            "roles": [
                                "agenda - Distribuidor",
                                "teste - teste"
                            ],
                            "locale": {
                                "language": "pt",
                                "region": "BR"
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    return console.dir(error); 
                }
                //console.log("inside: " + response.body);
                resolve(response.body);
            });
        });
    };//end function - retornaTokenDn
```

but this return the following erro message.

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND urlqa-api.apps.pd01e.edc1.cf.company.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:64:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'urlqa-api.apps.pd01e.edc1.cf.company.com'
}
```

**
The real problema is, this error only occur when I'm using a VPN connection to connect the network company. Using my home network this work normally.**

Or when I'm using vpn and send a request by postman using the same options the response is 200 , ok.

I'm using this method in a protractor automated test, I apreciate any help u can do. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Alan,
is there a proxy server somewhere in between?

Comment: HI Konstantin!!, yes

Comment: Hi Konstantin, one simple question solve the problem, thank you for you attention.

I set the proxy in cmd where I run the tests and the error did  not occurr, very thank you!!

Comment: Been there a lot of times ;) If I make this an answer, would you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the `ENOTFOUND` error is dependent on your network, I'd check if there is a proxy server in one of the networks.